# MitAppInventor - Arguments containing different datatypes prevented the access to convert the units

Tags: app-inventor

I am trying to make an app for converting unit values using Mit- app-inventor. While assigning input values, it's not processing.

[image]

The code above is taken from the code i've been working on. How to improve the code and where to find the input function to convert the units?

I expected the code to convert the units from pounds to kg when you enter the value, however the arguments  weren't able to convert as there were two different datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

None of your blocks make much sense. This should be all you need to display the converted value to the screen. (You can amend as you require)

[image]

Comment: I tried out The following code but doesn’t work Unfortunately. Can you try to figure out the reason for it?

Comment: Those blocks work OK for me, difficult to know the reason your blocks do not work unless you show them. You may get more/better help and support on the AppInventor Community - https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/login